# How to center forms in html and keep questions alignes as well?

Tags: html, css, alignment, text-alignment, formatting

I have a quick question, I have already created

```
<style type="text/css"> 
      .container {
       width: 100%;
      clear: both;
       text-align:center;

}
.container input {
    width: 2%;
    clear: both;

}
</style>
```

To center a form options that I am planning on doing. And it works. The circle bubbles that i have center in the middle, however when I try to add a name the "circle checkmarks" are no longer aligned. Is there a way that I can fix this without messing around with the

```
<Input type = radio Name = r1 Value = "WhatEver" onClick =GetSelectedItem()>Whatever<BR>
```

I have attached a Link to images to make it easier to understand.
[image]
[image]

Comment: Add your full HMTL code

Answer (score 0):

Add a div around the bullets and make it `text-align:left; margin:0 auto`
 and remove `width:2%` from the `input`

```
.form{
    text-align:left; 
    margin:0 auto;
    display:inline-block
}
.container input {
    clear: both;
}
```

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/zZjx4/1/)**

Comment: @user2060749 I didn't get u

Answer (score 0):

Please find below code, which will do the needful.

**CSS:**

```
.container, .container p {
     width: 100%;
     text-align:center;
}
.container p { padding:0 0 5px 0; }
.container input {
    width: 2%;
    margin:0 5px 0 0;
}
```

**HTML:**

```
<div class="container">
    <p><Input type = radio Name = r1 Value = "WhatEver" onClick =GetSelectedItem()><label>Whatever</label></p>
    <p><Input type = radio Name = r1 Value = "WhatEver" onClick =GetSelectedItem()><label>Whatever</label></p>
    <p><Input type = radio Name = r1 Value = "WhatEver" onClick =GetSelectedItem()><label>Whatever</label></p>
    <p><Input type = radio Name = r1 Value = "WhatEver" onClick =GetSelectedItem()><label>Whatever</label></p>
    <p><Input type = radio Name = r1 Value = "WhatEver" onClick =GetSelectedItem()><label>Whatever</label></p>
    <p><Input type = radio Name = r1 Value = "WhatEver" onClick =GetSelectedItem()><label>Whatever</label></p>
    <p><Input type = radio Name = r1 Value = "WhatEver" onClick =GetSelectedItem()><label>Whatever</label></p>
    <p><Input type = radio Name = r1 Value = "WhatEver" onClick =GetSelectedItem()><label>Whatever</label></p>
</div>
```